# XAML doesn't recognize code in code-behind

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

I am trying to bind the variable "CalorieGoal" to a textblock in XAML.  However, whenever I try to do so, I get the error "The type "local:NutritionInfo" was not found," and, "The name 'NutritionInfo' does not exist in the namespace "NutrientTracker [program name]." Why is this?

I have made sure that my syntax is exact.
XAML Code:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ContentRoot">
            <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:NutritionInfo">
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="250" Margin="0,450,0,0">
                        <Rectangle Fill="Beige" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" Width="639" Height="250" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Goal:" FontSize="18" Margin="7,50,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Eaten:" FontSize="18" Margin="7,120,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Remaining:" FontSize="18" Margin="7,190,0,0"/>

                        <TextBlock Text="Calories:" FontSize="18" Margin="140,10,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Fat(g):" FontSize="18" Margin="270,10,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Carbs(g):" FontSize="18" Margin="380,10,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Protein(g):" FontSize="18" Margin="520,10,0,0"/>

                        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Margin="-290,50,0,0" Name="lblCalorieGoal" Text="{Binding }"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        </ContentControl>
```

C#:

```
 public LogFood()
    {


        this.InitializeComponent();
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite =
           (Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue)localSettings.Values["nutritionSettings"];



        int calorieMin = Convert.ToInt32(composite["calorieMin"]);
        int calorieMax = Convert.ToInt32(composite["calorieMax"]);
        int gramsFatMin = Convert.ToInt32(composite["gramsFatMin"]);
        int gramsFatMax = Convert.ToInt32(composite["gramsFatMax"]);
        int gramsCarbsMin = Convert.ToInt32(composite["gramsCarbsMin"]);
        int gramsCarbsMax = Convert.ToInt32(composite["gramsCarbsMax"]);
        int gramsProteinMin = Convert.ToInt32(composite["gramsProteinMin"]);
        int gramsProteinMax = Convert.ToInt32(composite["gramsProteinMax"]);





        ContentRoot.Content = new NutritionInfo()
        {
            CalorieGoal = "1243"
        };











    }

    public class NutritionInfo
    {
        public string CalorieGoal { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: please, fix your code formatting. It's unreadable.

Comment: Your posted code is not _complete_, as it fails to include the two most interesting/useful aspects of the code: the actual declaration of the `NutritionInfo` type, including its namespace, and the XML namespace declarations at the top of the XAML file. Most likely, you've made an error in one or both of those. You've also failed to reduce the code example to the _minimal_ amount of code required to reproduce the issue. Please read [mcve] and [ask] for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way. And keep in mind that your question almost certainly ...

Comment: ... already has an answer, which you can find using the Stack Overflow search features.